# Flutter - Push FlatButton at near bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to push the flatbutton.icon near bottom but not in bottomNavigationBar. 
I want also to make it dynamic so that i can add more buttons vertically if needed.
I'm thinking of using Stack then positioned but i'm not familiar on how to implement it.

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              AvatarGlow(
                endRadius: 90,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                glowColor: Colors.white24,
                repeat: true,
                repeatPauseDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                startDelay: Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: Material(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                      child: FlutterLogo(
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                      radius: 50.0,
                    )),
              ),
              DelayedAimation(
                child: Text(
                  "PICKNIC",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
                delay: delayedAmount + 1000,
              ),FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
                    },
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.1),
                    icon: new Icon(MdiIcons.facebook, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark), 
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    label: Text(
                      'Login with Facebook',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check following solutions:

1. If you need 1 button, simply use FloatingActionButton [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)
2. If you need multiple suggest this [article](https://medium.com/@kaendagger/test-cef30fcb5c54) (Column with FABs)
3. And animated solution looks more user friendly [package](https://pub.dev/packages/unicorndial)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the content centered in the available space above the buttons, you could put your content centered in a `Expanded` widget and put the buttons below it, like this:

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AvatarGlow(...),
            DelayedAimation(...),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      FlatButton.icon(...),
      FlatButton.icon(...),
    ],
  ),
)
```

If you want to have the content centered in the entire screen and the buttons at the bottom, you could use a `Stack`, like this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AvatarGlow(...),
          DelayedAimation(...),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(...),
          FlatButton.icon(...),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```